# How to know permission for a user using REST in a site sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, designer

How do I know in what level of permission e.g (Full control, Edit, Design) or group e.g (Owner, approvers, designers, etc) an user is, using REST?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi for you can use the rest endpoint for current logged in user

```
_api/Web/CurrentUser?$expand=groups&$select=groups/Title,Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provided details of knowing the permissions at

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx